# using jsontocsv npm, how to give different headers other than json keys

Tags: javascript, npm

I am able to convert the json to csv using JsontoCsv npm library but, I want to update new headers instead of the json keys, how to do that.

My code is as below:(followed the steps mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)

```
const { parse } = require('json2csv');

const fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'];
const newFields = ['new field1', 'new field2', 'new field3'];
const opts = { fields };

try {
  const csv = parse(myData, opts);
  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

output will be as below:

```
field1, field2, field3
value1, value2, value3
value11, value12, value13
```

I want to update the csv headers and expecting the output must be as below:

```
'new field1', 'new field2', 'new field3'
value1, value2, value3
value11, value12, value13
```

Comment: use `const opts = { newFields };` instead of `const opts = { fields };` what issue?

Comment: even, if i do that, I got the headers as 'fields' instead of 'newFields'